# How to create small binary with GNU as/GNU ld?

Tags: assembly, gnu, ld

I like AT&T syntax of amd64 assembler, so I am using GNU As. Unfortunately, I fail to create binaries of reasonable size with it. For compraison, trivial program, that just exits with value 1, implemented in fasm:

```
;; a02.fasm
format ELF64 executable at 0000000100000000h    ; put image over 32-bit limit

segment readable executable

entry $

    xor edi,edi     ; exit code 0
    inc edi
    mov eax,60      ; sys_exit
    syscall
```

complied in following way

```
$ fasm a02.fasm
flat assembler  version 1.73.06  (16384 kilobytes memory)
1 passes, 131 bytes.
```

results in tiny binary.

Equivalent program, compiled and linked with binutils

```
# a01.S
.globl _start
_start:
    xor %di, %di
    inc %di
    mov $60, %eax
    syscall
```

with following commands:

```
as a01.S -o a01.o
ld a01.o
```

results in huge binary:

```
$ du -hb a.out
4744    a.out
$ strip -s a.out
$ du -hb a.out
4408    a.out
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
```

Both `as` and `ld` are from Debian package `binutils=2.31.1-11`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 4000 bytes is not huge, especially considering a disk block is probably at least 4k and memory pages too. ELF format includes some overhead which is usually negligible compared to the whole binary.  There are tricks to make it smaller, but normally not worth the trouble and the possible violation of the standards. PS: `incb %di` should not even assemble, I doubt you are really showing the code you tested with.

Comment: That said, look at [sstrip from Kickers of ELF](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/elfkickers.html). It stripped the binary down to 133 bytes for me although even the plain `as`+`ld` combo produced 664 bytes here.

Comment: Bug. Replaced `incb` with `inc`. I know, that ELF have overhead, but why `fasm` produces hundred of bytes of overhead, while `gas/ld` produces thousands?

Comment: `sstrip` saved several hundreds bytes only.

Comment: Maybe your tools use some default settings that produce large binaries, e.g. `pie`. I have GNU Binutils for Debian 2.28. What does `file a.out` say?

Comment: Updated question with output of `file`. How can I disable those default settings?

Comment: Looks like binutils switched to `gold` by default but still has `ld.bfd` available. See if using that makes a difference. Yeah, just tested `gold` produces that "large" binary. Actually `ld.bfd` does too. Oops.

Comment: No significant difference found. Still over 4K.

Comment: Looks like it is because of the (apparently unconditional) support for the `.note.gnu.property` section.

Comment: Just tried `lld` from `clang` suite. Even worse, 8K.

Comment: As I said, it's normally not an issue. Your programs are much bigger than the overhead. If you **really** insist, downgrade to binutils 2.28 or do some `ld` and `objcopy` magic to get rid of that section. Admittedly, `ld` should have an option to disable generation of the `.note.gnu.property`.

Comment: `inc %di` is 16-bit operand-size.  That takes an extra `66` prefix byte, so it's bigger than `inc %edi`.  If you want to golf down the `.text` section, `push $1` / `pop %rdi` / `lea 60 - 1 (%rdi), %eax`.  (3 bytes + 3 bytes)  [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981)  (But of course this is only a trivial saving vs. the extra sections that the linker includes by default.)

Comment: Or take advantage of the fact that Linux in practice zeros the registers before running `_start`, so you can just take advantage of a 2-byte `inc` and 3-byte `lea`.  Or 2-byte `mov  $60, %al` + 3 byte `mov $1, %dil` or `lea 1-60(%rax), %edi`

Comment: For extra evil, assume `argc==1` so you can just `pop %rdi` :D

Comment: I get 664 bytes as well with binutils, 344 after using strip.  didnt try sstrip.

Comment: `strip --remove-section=.note.gnu.property ./a.out` might get rid of that property if it exists.

Comment: Binary segfaults after that.

Comment: It takes some messing around with `ld` and `objcopy` to get rid of the section without a segfault. Hardly worth the trouble.